# Trying to find Latin resource I used to have years ago

Tags: resource-request

Once I found online an old (I believe 16th century, but not sure) list of simple sentences, Latin and their English translation side by side. I've tried with no avail to find them again through google, and I looked through my old Latin folders because I knew I had a few pages printed out at one point. But I guess threw them out. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're going to need more detail to help you with this kind of request. Do you remember anything else about it?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I've been trying to rack my brain to remember the author or the title. I've gone through my old folders and flashdrives. Nothing yet. But I'm not expecting a miracle, this was just my last resort

Comment: This might have to be closed then. Although you would obviously recognize the resource, the description you provide probably fits a huge number of different sources, and it's anyone's guess which is appropriate. You could rephrase it as a resource request ("What are some examples of 16th century Latin instructional textbooks").

Answer (score 7):

Mathurin Cordier was a theologian and teacher of the 16th century, and his work, known as the [*Corderii Colloquiorum*](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Mathurin_CORDIER_Corderii_colloquiorum_centuria_se?id=daZgAAAAcAAJ), sounds a lot like what you're describing. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's quite possible that you remember the Eton Latin Grammar of (Arthur?) Hay, in widespread use in English public schools a couple of hundred years ago. It was adapted from the sixteenth century Eton instruction manual, but was much revised over the years and published in two parts. I remember from years ago an edition published in the 1880s by John Murray (London), which was partly constructed in the way you describe. You could begin your search by looking at https://www.forgottenbooks.com/en/books/TheEtonLatinGrammar_10853396

[Added later] This is a sample from the source I suggested, returned to the two-column form used by Hay, as nearly as I can manage it:

(246) Qui signiﬁcans causam éxigit ut es stultus qui crédas huic (homini). //
*Who, signifying the cause, requires a subjunctivum (modum) subjunctive mood as, you are a fool who can beliéve, that is, for beliéving  this fellow*.

Ut pro postquam sicut quomodo jungitur indicativo (modo) autém cum dénotat quamquam utpoté ﬁnitem causam jungitur subjunctivo (modo) ut, ut sumus in Ponto, Ister constitit frigoro tér. // *That or after that, or, since that, as, at and how, is joined to an indicative mood, but when it implies or signiﬁes although, for as much as,or the final cause, it is joined to a subjunctive    mood: as, since that we are in Pontus, the  Danube has stood with cold, that is, has been frozen three times.*

I hope that this is helpful to you.